# Inserting Multiple rows into User Defined table type from a string value while using dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Have a table where a column houses a stored procedure to be executed for each row in a cursor or loop this  procedure has table valued parameter as input parameters the procedure being called for each row gets its values from the other columns in the same table based on an update statement using `dynamic sql` which populates the column and gives the procedure its values . One of the columns being used to supply values to the procedure has a string value consisting of many rows however the for `XML PATH ('')` was used to convert the value to a single one line string. This string needs to passed into the  a user defined table type input parameter for the procedure .

How can I get this string value to be inserted especially when it has multiple rows sometimes , meaning I need to make multiple inserts into the user defined table type variable for that row of execution.  *

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Insert into Table tablename (col1,col2,..,coln) values (call storedprocedurename(arg1,arg2,..,argn))

Note : No.of attributes in insert query should equal with no.of attribute which stored procedure returns. And also in same order